# Threshold for votes in the Sandbox before posting in the main site?

Tags: discussion, sandbox, voting

Recently, I posted my first post on the main site for Code Golf, and it was poorly received because I am a newcomer to the site. I was asked to post it in the sandbox, [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20749/95652). As of now, it has one vote, and I doubt that is sufficient enough to have confidence to post it on the main site. So how many votes in the sandbox would be sufficient to be mostly confident that a question would be well received in the main?

Comment: Typically, +3 is a good target. Be sure to ask in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte) for feedback as well

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing First comment: No, this question and its answers did not give me a clear idea of the recommended vote count. You can turn your second post into an answer; but could you please clarify, does it mean 3 upvotes or a net score of +3?

Comment: The "does this answer your question" comment is an autocomment by the system when someone votes to close as a duplicate. I've voted to close this as a duplicate of that post because answers to this question should be posted to the FAQ post, rather than being scattered around across multiple different questions. I've edited into the FAQ a note about score as it was missing. Generally, +3 net score, but keep in mind that downvotes are rare in the Sandbox, and generally indicate that a challenge would not be well received, rather than that it isn't ready to be posted

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Yes, I am aware that the previous comment was automatic. I put that there to notify other viewers that this is not a duplicate of the post you suggested

Comment: Honestly, I would look more at "have I addressed all pertinent issues raised in comments" rather than the number of votes. Or, if there's no comments, that enough time has passed. Sometimes people upvote a cool challenge concept in the Sandbox without looking deeply to check that everything is in order.

Comment: Pro-tip: If you don't get enough feedback in the sandbox, ask for more feed back in [the chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte).

Comment: The problem that there isn't enough people reviewing the sandbox has been there for a long time, and unfortunately there's no cure for it except by asking people to review it. (when you're sufficiently familiar with it you can review too)